# How do I use find operators on node-orm2 fields?

Tags: node.js, orm, node-orm2

Node-ORM2 documentation states this:

1.2.1 Operators

To use more than a straightforward = or in operator you use a slightly different syntax like so:

```
model.find({
    field : { "operator" : "value" }
});
```

Those operators are:

```
Operator Values to use operator
Equals =
Less Than <, “less than”
Less Than or Equal to <=, “less than or equal to”
More than >, “more than”
More than or equal to >=, “more than or equal to”
```

Trying to filter a find where a fields is greater than like so:

```
Person.find({id: {">": 1000}}, function(err, res) {
});
```

The resulting query looks like this...

```
... WHERE `id` = `>` = `1000` ...
```

I also tried using the text operators "less than", it gives the same result.
How can I do a WHERE `id` > 1000 query with node-orm2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking at the wrong documentation, if anyone is looking for the same answer, look at: https://github.com/dresende/node-orm2#conditions